# Why can't I duplicate an MJPEG stream from a webcam to a V4L2 Loopback Device on Linux?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, raspbian, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I'm trying to duplicate a USB webcam device V4L2 stream (/dev/video0) to a V4L2 Loopback Device (/dev/video99) at the highest resolution and framerate possible with the hardware available on a Raspberry Pi 4 running the latest Raspbian (also the minimum CPU load). I'm using FFMPEG version 7:4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt2 and v4l2loopback version 0.12.5.1.

The output from:
`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0` gives me the following:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xc1e1c0] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 1600x1200 3264x2448 2592x1944 2048x1536 1280x960 1024x768 800x600 640x480 320x240 1600x1200
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xc1e1c0] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 1600x1200 3264x2448 2592x1944 2048x1536 1280x960 1024x768 800x600 640x480 320x240 1600x1200
```

3264x2448px is the native CCD resolution, and the image is being used for machine vision purposes, so I'd like to use this maximum resolution at the highest framerate I can. The reason for the loopback device is so that I can view/stream the videofeed (with GStreamer) and take high resolution PNG snapshots simultaneously, using the command `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 3264x2448 -i /dev/video99 -frames 1 capture.png -y` From my understanding this means there is an MJPEG stream at this resolution and according to the command `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext` I can manage 15fps:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        Size: Discrete 1600x1200
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 3264x2448
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 2592x1944
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 2048x1536
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x960
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1024x768
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1600x1200
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 1600x1200
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 3264x2448
            Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 2592x1944
            Interval: Discrete 0.333s (3.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 2048x1536
            Interval: Discrete 0.333s (3.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x960
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1024x768
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1600x1200
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
```

I feel like I've tried every possible version of GStreamer/FFMPEG command to achieve this and have had varying success, but more often than not I come up against "av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory" or some issue with converting M-JPEG to rawvideo for the loopback device...

What command should I be using? I'm at the end of my tether!

I've tried:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "image/jpeg,width=3264,height=2448,framerate=15/1" ! avdec_mjpeg ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=3264,height=2448,framerate=15/1" ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video99
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 3264x2448 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuyv422 -r 1 -f v4l2 /dev/video99
```

(EDIT) gives:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 14226.770484, bitrate: 255688 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 3264x2448, 255688 kb/s, 2 fps, 2 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video99':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 3264x2448, q=2-31, 127844 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 rawvideo
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A speed=15.8x    
video:15606kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 3264x2448 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 15 -f v4l2 /dev/video99
```

(EDIT) gives:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 13704.103283, bitrate: 255688 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 3264x2448, 255688 kb/s, 2 fps, 2 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video99':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 3264x2448, q=2-31, 1438248 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 rawvideo
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 7 times
frame=    8 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.53 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0 speed=1.37x    
video:93636kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video99
```

(EDIT) gives:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0xdb5240] EOI missing, emulating
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 12511.425271, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3264x2448, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xdb7f10] V4L2 output device supports only a single raw video stream
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I'm not sure what to troubleshoot next - looking at available memory, there's no problem, so what am I doing wrong? This copy of the feed is the last piece of the puzzle...

Comment: Copy & paste all text from the log from your last ffmpeg command.

Comment: Thanks man, I was hoping you'd respond! I've followed a LOT of your posts thus far...

Comment: I've added the output from the previous two before - they both give the memory allocation error. As they are not the MJPEG input, I suspect they are only capable of 2fps at that resolution, which is really not ideal! Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Does the problem only occur on the Raspberry Pi? Can you duplicate it on a linux desktop? 4.1 is old. Try git master, or 4.4 at least.

Comment: I only have a Raspberry PI and that's also what the final version will be running on... so if I can't get it to work on a Pi, then there's no help... It looks like I have the wrong syntax for the MJPEG stream, so I really want to make sure that's right before I have to resort to the raw video stream. Do you have any suggestions on what I could change for that line? Building 4.4 from source may be a little beyond my capabilities!

Comment: Some further discoveries... I can stream the mjpeg stream from the camera to an mjpeg file using ```ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 15 -video_size 3264x2448 -i /dev/video0 -c copy -t 10 output1.mjpeg``` but it only seems to manage 2-3fps from the output. I can also play this mjpeg file using ```ffplay -i output1.mjpeg``` - so why can't I send it to the loopback device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, so I'll write what I've got so far. I'm having a similar issue, but using an RPi3 and am trying to stream from a webcam at 1440p to two loopback devices. One will be used for live streaming and the other for computer vision.

## ffmpeg

I've got it to work, but the stream is 6-12 FPS, with a speed of 0.2-0.4x (too slow for what I want). I don't know how to fix this. Note the below is for 1 stream, but can easily be duplicated for two streams.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -vcodec mjpeg -s 2560x1440 -i /dev/video0 -map 0:v -vcodec rawvideo -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

`hide_banner` hides a lot of the text
`-vcodec rawvideo` is already assumed, so isn't necessary
`-vf format=yuv420p` is used to convert pixel fmts ot smth v4l2 supports. I think this is the issue, because pixels are being converted, when what I (we) actually want is to send the compressed mjpeg stream directly to the loopback device.

Note that I didn't specify `-r` as it seemed to increase performance.

## gst

This gives me corrupted images while streaming, but is very fast. By corrupted, I mean the colours are funky and sometimes the image is "boxy".

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/videoX t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/videoY

Source: comment by Olivier in
[duplicate webcam stream in a virtual device created with v4l2loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664945/duplicate-webcam-stream-in-a-virtual-device-created-with-v4l2loopback)

Note: I wrote this from my phone and don't know how to set the formatting, so I apologise for that.